# Change Red Hat terminal color?

Tags: shell, terminal, colors, redhat

Any action with color does not work.

Example:

```
# setterm -foreground green
# setterm -background red
```

Red Hat 7.6

Suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How change Red Hat terminal color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60822586/how-change-red-hat-terminal-color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Red Hat:

## setterm -term linux -foreground cyan

Comment: Just to add one more thing, if you want to persist the color change across terminal sessions, paste the above command in .bashrc file .